# Restart browser between tests

Tags: selenium, webdriver

How to restart browser between tests?
I have DrivErFactory and in the BasePage in constructor I call

```
public BasePage() {
    this.driver = DriverFactory.getDriver();
    this.wait = new WebDriverWait(getDriver(), waitTime);
}
```

Then in my tests I have:

```
@BeforeMethod
public void beforeTest() {
loginPage.open();}
```

and

```
@AfterMethod
    public void afterTest() {
        loginPage.quitDriver();
    }
```

**After first test** I get:
*org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?*

If I use in After:

```
loginPage.closeDriver();
```

I have:
*org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session*

In *BeforeTest* WebDriver can start so why he doesn't start after *AfterTest*?

How to do better? How to restart browser before each test?

**DriverFactory**

```
public class DriverFactory {
    static PropertyBase propertyBase = new PropertyBase();
    Properties prop = new Properties();

    private static WebDriver driver;

    private static void setChromeDriverPath() {
        String chromeDriverPath = ".\\resources\\chromedriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriverPath);
    }

    private static void setFireFoxDriverPath() {
        String chromeDriverPath = ".\\resources\\geckodriver.exe";
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", chromeDriverPath);
    }

    private static void configureDriver() {
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    private static FirefoxProfile setFireFoxProfile() {
        FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.dir", "./downloads");
        profile.setPreference("browser.download.folderList", 2);
        profile.setPreference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", 
            "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;"); 
        profile.setPreference( "browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", false );
        profile.setPreference( "pdfjs.disabled", true );
        return profile;
    }

    private static ChromeOptions setChromeProfile() {
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        prefs.put("download.prompt_for_download", true);
        prefs.put("download.default_directory", "./download");
        options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
        return options;
    }

    private static WebDriver createChromeDriver(){
        setChromeDriverPath();
        return driver = new ChromeDriver(setChromeProfile());
    }

    private static WebDriver createFireFoxDriver(){
        setFireFoxDriverPath();
        return driver = new FirefoxDriver(setFireFoxProfile());
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        String browserType = propertyBase.getProperty("browser");

        switch (browserType) {
        case "chrome":
            if (driver==null) {
                driver = createChromeDriver();
            }
            break;
        case "firefox":
            if (driver==null) {
                createFireFoxDriver();
            }
            break;
        }
        configureDriver();
        return driver;
    }
```

Comment: can you share the code for getDriver method?

Comment: Please clarify, When Or at which point you wants to again Restart browser.

Comment: restart before each test

Comment: Show the code of function `loginPage.quiteDriver()` and `loginPage.closeDriver()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a method to get a driver object from the factory. Maybe you should make a method there to close it as well. You now call it on the loginpage. That does not seem very logical. However the important thing is probably to close the driver with driver.quit() or driver.close() AND then make sure to set driver=null;

That way, when you run a new test, the getDriver is called and the if (driver == null) ensures that a new object is instanciated.

If my assumption is right then this should do the trick, otherwise please post whatever you have in loginPage.quitDriver().

Something like this, inside DriverFactory class

```
public static void quitDriver() {
    driver.quit();
    driver = null;
}
```

edit:typos

Comment: Yes that works :) thanks, dude ! also thanks for tip about loginPage.quitDriver().

Comment: If it does, maybe you can accept the answer so people know this question has been answered. Thx